# Access state from reducer to action creator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, es6-promise

i want to access my initialState from reducer to action creator

i have tried getState but its not working

here is my reducer.js

```
const initialState = { 
  current_user: null, 
}
```

and here is my action creator function

```
import store from './reducer

export const get_vaults_index =(form) => async (dispatch , getState) =>{

form = {
       user_id: store.getState().initialState.current_user
    }

const response = await axios.post('url', form );
  dispatch({ 
    type: types.INDEX_VAULTS ,
    payload: response
  }); }
```

Comment: just an advise my friend, redux lifecycle is supposed to go in one direction component>action creators>action>reducers>component, what you are trying to achieve is an anti pattern, a possible side effect.

if you needed to get the initial state you should pass it from the component as you are consuming it from the reducers when dispatching your action

Answer (score 0):

I m assuming that you are using `redux-thunk` here, you don't need to import store from reducer. `getState` argument can give the latest values from the redux store.

```
export const get_vaults_index =(form) => async (dispatch , getState) =>{

form = {
       user_id:getState().current_user
    }

const response = await axios.post('url', form );
  dispatch({ 
    type: types.INDEX_VAULTS ,
    payload: response
  }); }
```

I will also advice you to use selectors to cherry pick the values from state and then pass it to the action.